# Can one install Whole Tomato's Visual Assist X in Microsoft's Visual C++ 2010 Express Edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

Do you know software support assist for Visual C++ 2010 Express ?, as Visual Assist X for Visual Studio

Comment: No, the Express editions don't support add-ons.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Installing any plugin requires running the IDE in Integrated Mode (rather than Isolated Mode), which means you'll need a full version of Visual Studio. The express editions simply don't have the feature.

Couple of options to get a version capable of Integrated Mode:

- If you are a university student, you can download a full version of Visual Studio from MSDNAA.
- If you are a student where MSDNAA is not available, you can still get the full copy from [DreanSpark](http://bit.ly/dYpBTO) if you can show proof of being a student. (A report card should suffice)
- You could purchase the full version of Visual Studio -- I'm assuming this is probably cost prohibitive.